# To Convert XML into Text format but also need to remove un-necessary tags

Tags: xml, vba

I am in need to converting 100s of XML files into text file but the problem is i only need specific tags in text file and not all the tags XML has.

Tags which are needed

```
Source
Date
Headline
Text
```

And tags which are not needed and should be removed

```
Digest
Day
VolumeNo
IssueNo
SourcePage
Section
City
Copyright
Doc-id
Category
Subject
Keyword
Country
```

Please note, one XML has multiple stories in it as well.

Any Help from anyone please.

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? Where are you stuck? Have you had a look to `MSXML2`? Lots of information on the web and here on SO.

Comment: @FunThomas I am very new to coding, I just have one code which read the XMLs and count specific tag and return value in excel. However, i will read MSXML2 :)

Comment: @FunThomas I wish if you could please send if there is any query which is matching my needs here on stackoverflow so that i can read and try myself. i will be thankful

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is best achieved with an XSLT stylesheet. It's hard to be specific without seeing your XML structure, but typically you will want something like the following. The first template rule is to copy the tags you want to retain, the second is to drop all the others.

```
<xsl:tranform version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Source|Date|Headline|Text">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Running this transformation on all the files in a directory depends a bit on what tools you are using and how comfortable you are, for example, writing a shell script. There are plenty of XSLT 1.0 processors around for most environments.

Comment: @Micheal Kay thank you sir, will check it and will revert

Comment: @Micheal Kay I would like to use it on the VBA, i am afraid i have never used Shell script. is it possible if you could please suggest anything in VBA or something else for non-technical people like me :)

Comment: I'm afraid I last used VBA about 30 years ago. I don't think it's a particularly good toolset for XML processing, but others may know better.

Comment: thanks for guidance, what tool you suggest is good for xml so that i will start reading and learning that

Comment: I would recommend investing in a license for Oxygen, which gives you access to a whole raft of XML tools including XSLT. If that's beyond your budget there are cheaper alternatives such as EditIX.

Comment: thanks for advise i will work on EditIX and will ask if any help required. thank you again

Comment: @Micheal Kay Can you please advise which application is suitable or can execute MSXML codes? I am seeing videos on Youtube but i cannot figure out which software they are using. thanks

Comment: Sorry, MSXML is very very old and that isn't where I would start.

Comment: EditIX is also a paid version and offers only 30 days of trial. Sir Can you please help me in creating any batch file which i just run and it will work accordingly, or any VBA code ?

Comment: Sorry, I've given you advice and you are free to reject it.